# JAXB + Mule. Avoid namespaces in XML transformations

Tags: java, jaxb, mule

I am a newbie at both JAXB and Mule. We have an application that would connect to various third parties, each providing their own XSDs to define message schemas.

If I define different JAXBContext objects for each third party, I get "more than one JAXBContext registered" error. So I have one context with packageNames separated by a colon (e.g. "com.myorg.pack1:com.myorg.pack2:com.myorg.pack3")

Now I am seeing namespaces getting generated in the messages even though the XSDs have element configured as unqualified. This only happens for the root node.

Unfortunately, the 3rd party i am interacting with does not give a response if there's a namespace.

Is there a way to not have the namespaces? Any pointers will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `elementFormDefault="qualified"` in your XML Schema this just means that only global (top level) elements are namespace qualified.  In JAXB the `@XmlRootElement` corresponds to a global element.  This element will be namespace qualified no matter how you create the `JAXBContext`.

### UPDATE

> got it, thanks. so there's really no way to avoid namespaces?

If the XML Schema contains a `targetNamespace` attribute then it is going to expect namespace qualification in the XML document.  If it specifies `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` then only global (top level) elements are namespace qualified.  This means that the default namespace prefix can't be used. This means:

1. There is no way to avoid namespaces if you want the XML document to be valid against your XML schema.
2. You can remove all namespace mapping from your JAXB model (i.e. `@XmlSchema` on the `package-info` class, or the namespace attribute on `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlElement`, etc.), but then the XML won't be valid against the XML Schema.

Comment: got it, thanks. so there's really no way to avoid namespaces?

Comment: @aishwarya - I have updated my answer to provide some additional info.  Is it the 3rd party that provided XML Schemas specifying namespace qualification that won't accept XML documents containing namespace qualification?